# How to fix the "Cannot open jks file" while ssl connection

Tags: mysql, ssl, jdbc, java-11, truststore

When I try to make a JDBC-based SSL connection to MySQL, I'm getting the following exception:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot open file://home/files/_jvm/bin/keystore.jks [home]

1. I tried to keep all properties in JDBC url
2. I tried passing in properties instance also

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Properties mysqlProperties = new Properties();
mysqlProperties.put("user", "root");
mysqlProperties.put("password", "root");
mysqlProperties.put("clientCertificateKeyStoreUrl", "file://home/files/_jvm/bin/keystore.jks");
mysqlProperties.put("clientCertificateKeyStorePassword", "mypass");
mysqlProperties.put("trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl", "file://home/files/_jvm/bin//truststore.jks");
mysqlProperties.put("trustCertificateKeyStorePassword", "mypass");
con = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db74?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true",
    mysqlProperties);
System.out.println(con.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName());
```

I expected to get database name with encrypted connection[ssl/tls based connection].

Comment: Have you tried using `file:/home/`... instead of `file://home/`...? Does the file actually exist and does your user have read access to that file?

Comment: Thanks for the above suggestion that worked for finding the file correctly and i am ended up with getting different exception as below. Could you help here what could be root cause and how it can be solved. com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot open file:/home/mysql_certs_latest/truststore [keystore password was incorrect]
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

Comment: The followed prior exceptions are as below: Caused by: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect
 at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2108)         Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted